# Unsupported Media Type while PUT

Tags: python, post, python-requests, put, http-status-code-415

I have a DRF server that accepts the following renders and parsers:

```
    "renders": [
    "application/json",
    "text/html"
],
"parses": [
    "multipart/form-data",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
],
```

When I am `POST`ing an image to .../snippets/, I receive 200 response code.

When I am trying to `POST` a JSON Object, I receive 415 response code.

Here is the snippet for `POST`:

```
Boxes = [{'X': 2423, 'Y': 532, 'W': 7456, 'H': 2345}]
res = json.dumps(Boxes)



r = requests.put(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/",
    data=json.dumps({"Boxes": res,

                     "Amount": '3'
                     }),
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token 7095dcc10e57301518f192a4e3a0fb275157cb2f', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
)
print(r.status_code)
```

I am able to make a `POST` request using Postman so, definitely I am missing something here.

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.
In my case I need to use `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and everything works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `json` request body

```
Boxes = [{'X': 2423, 'Y': 532, 'W': 7456, 'H': 2345}]

r = requests.put(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/1/",
    json={"Boxes": Boxes, "Amount":"3" },
    headers={'Authorization': 'Token 7095dcc10e57301518f192a4e3a0fb275157cb2f', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
)

print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: Did not work, still 415